# exception( Input string wasn't in the correct format )

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagrid

I execute this code:

```
  t1.Rows[gid].Cells[3].Paragraphs.First()
                              .Append((Int32.Parse(calculateGetunitPrice(tblMaterialGroup.id))*(a+b+c)).ToString())
                              .FontSize(12)
                              .Font(new FontFamily("B Nazanin"));
```

The value of a and b and c is:

```
a=24121
b=0
c=13311
```

and "calculateGetunitPrice(tblMaterialGroup.id)" is 1

I got this error:

```
Input string wasn't in the correct format
```

Here is my calculateGetunitPrice function:

```
public string calculateGetunitPriceForElse(int materialGroupId)
    {

        var q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderAnnouncePrices
                where i.companyId == _comWinnerID && i.MaterialGroupId == materialGroupId
                select i.PriceForElse;

       // int? sum = g => g.PriceForElse;
        return q.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: Obviously `calculateGetunitPrice(tblMaterialGroup.id))*(a+b+c)).ToString()` is not in correct format. Check with debugger value for this expression.

Comment: Can you post your entire call stack?

Comment: So how can i do that?

Comment: at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean

Comment: @Spad, it is not entire call stack, please show also value of str.

Comment: I execute this line of code and i got the same error :calculateGetunitPrice(tblMaterialGroup.id)

Comment: can you provide `calculateGetunitPrice` code?

Comment: yes i wrote that in the question

Comment: q is collection so use `q.First().ToString()` or something like this

Comment: @Grundy :thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code

```
var q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderAnnouncePrices
        where i.companyId == _comWinnerID && i.MaterialGroupId == materialGroupId
        select i.PriceForElse;
```

q is `IEnumerable` or `IQueriable` but not `int`, so when you call `ToString()` its not returns numeric
so to solve you need get single value with something functions like `First`, `Single`, `Sum` etc
change code like this

```
var q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderAnnouncePrices
        where i.companyId == _comWinnerID && i.MaterialGroupId == materialGroupId
        select i.PriceForElse;

return q.First().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input string wasn't in the correct format` is an exception from `Int32.Parse(...)` so make sure it is a number, maybe you have some whitespace in it.